# Bower and dependency development

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman, bower

I'm developing an application `myapp` using angularJS with Yeoman Generator. This includes Bower to manage dependencies, and Grunt to wiredep those dependencies into index.html (=It generates index.html file with all scripts and links based on bower configuration and dependencies).

I have `angular-gantt` as a dependency, which is distributed through Bower as a single `.js` file.

As I want to contribute to `angular-gantt`, i've used `bower link` to read sources from a local cloned git repository.

But i still need to override the bower `main` property from `myapp` to use the [javascript source files from this folder](https://github.com/Schweigi/angular-gantt/tree/master/src), instead of the [single distributed one](https://github.com/Schweigi/angular-gantt/blob/master/assets/angular-gantt.js).

Is there an automated way to to this, without listing one by one each source files ? Is there some generator to build this list from sources ?

***myapp/bower.json***

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "angular-gantt": "~0.6.1",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "overrides": {
    ...
    "angular-gantt": {
      "main": [ // <= How to avoid listing those files manually ?
        "file1.js",
        "file2.js",
        "file3.js",
        "file4.js",
        ....
      ]
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

***angular-gantt/bower.json***

```
{
  "name": "angular-gantt",
  "version": "0.6.1",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Schweigi/angular-gantt",
  "authors": [
    "Schweigi"
  ],
  "description": "A Gantt chart directive for Angular.js without any other dependencies.",
  "main": [
    "./assets/angular-gantt.js",
    "./assets/gantt.css"
  ],
  .......
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting question. I know Visual Studio allows you to put JavaScript comments in your files declaring what it depends on, but I'm not sure if there is a non Visual Studio solution.

Comment: why do you override the bower `main` property and not use the single distributed one?

Comment: If i make changes, i wan't them to be in the right source file. I   don't wan't to spend time copy/pasting changes from distributed file to source file.

Answer (score 0):

If other people have this problem, here is the solution i've finally found.

`angular-gantt` is using grunt [concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) and [uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) that both supports `sourceMap` option. When enabled, a sourceMap is generated along with distribution `.js` file.

[Intellij IDEA can read this sourcemap](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2013/03/coffeescript-debugging-with-sourcemaps-in-webstorm-6-phpstorm-6/) to debug from real sources while keeping the distributed file in the runtime environment. This require no configuration, as the sourceMap filename is added as a comment to the end of the distribution `.js` file.

With a grunt file [watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch), minified file can be automatically generated when sources are changed.

So by using an IDE supporting sourceMap, and grunt watch to check changes and build distributed `.js` file on source changes, the problem is solved.